# OAuth client_id and client_secret

Tags: oauth

I aware that `client_id` and `client_secret` are assigned to client by the auth server.
`client_id` can be exposed while `client_secret` must be kept as a secret.

I just don't understand, why, in this case, would we need a `client_id`.

Isn't just the `client_secret` enough to identify the client app?

Comment: Did you got a chance to look at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557204/why-do-we-need-both-client-id-and-client-secret-instead-of-just-clientsecret)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about client_id and client_secret in a similar way to username and password.

In the same way you identify a user with a username, you can identify a client/application with client_id, client_id can be public, but the secret needs to be kept private.

The authentication server can have multiple clients registered, therefore it needs to be able to identify a tuple of id and secret to start the flow.